# How to target second child element of a div using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if this is possible, I rarely do when I ask questions on this site, but everyone keeps telling me to use jQuery to do so. I make websites, but I am VERY novice at all of this and would prefer to get solid grip on Javascript before moving forward.

Anyways, my question is "Is it possible to target a second child (i.e.

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div> <!--This one-->
</div>
```

using JAVASCRIPT in order to manipulate it? If so, how?"

My previous attempt didn't work, I had a strong feeling it wouldn't but, all the same.

```
function activateEvent(obj) {
    obj.secondChild.style.display="block";};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
obj.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling
```

([doesn't work in IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html))

Or

```
obj.children[1]
```

Comment: `obj.firstChild.nextSibling` would get the first Element node assuming the HTML is as in the example (the text node containing the line break and the spaces is the first child).

Comment: Thank you SLaks, that obj.children[1] is a really useful thing, thank you again! :)

Answer (score -3):

You really should try to learn jQuery because it will make things a lot easier for you. Get the basics from plain Javascript and then learn a library like jQuery. you just need to load it into your website, then you can target the element in your exemple using: `$('.parent div:nth-child(2)')`
It's that easy.

Comment: I know, and I will! : ) I just need time to get used to Javascript. I see all these things being done on other websites (with jQuery) and I AM SO JEALOUS! But, I'm just not there yet. ;P

Comment: `easier` doesn't mean always `better`.

Comment: The `javascript` tag says *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*